# minimum value from a list of dataobject returns The method min(Comparator<? super EggsHatched>) error

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class that holds a model for values of minimum object as shown here

```
public class ModelObject implements Serializable {

 private Long min;

//getters and setters
```

I created a list of this model in a controller as shown

```
List<ModelObject > modelObject = new ArrayList<>();

for(EggsHatched hatched: eggsList) {


EggsHatched minByEgg = eggsList
                  .stream()
                  .min(minByEgg.getHatched()) //here throws error of The method min(Comparator<? super EggsHatched>) in the type Stream<EggsHatched> is not applicable for the arguments (Long)
                  .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

 modelObject.setMin(minByEgg);// I cannot do this here because the above gives me error

}
```

Please how can I get the minimum value from the eggsList

Comment: what is EggsHatched？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minByEgg.getHatched()` is not a `Comparator<EggsHatched>` , so you can't pass it to `min`.

Use:

```
EggsHatched minByEgg = eggsList
                  .stream()
                  .min(Comparator.comparing(EggsHatched::getHatched))
                  .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

P.S., it's not clear why you put the stream pipeline inside a loop that iterates over `eggsList`. When you use `Stream`s, you don't need the loop.

`modelObject.setMin(minByEgg)` also doesn't make sense, since `modelObject` is a `List`, which doesn't have a `setMin` method.

If you want to calculate numeric properties of the `getHatched()` value of all the elements in your `List` (such as minimum, maximum and average), you can map to a `LongStream` and call `summaryStatistics`:

```
LongSummaryStatistics stats = eggsList
                  .stream()
                  .mapToLong(EggsHatched::getHatched)
                  .summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: can I use the same approach to get the max value

Comment: @rocket you can, but in a separate Stream pipeline (by calling max() instead of min()).

Comment: @rocket How would you define an average on a `List<EggHatched>`? If you want to compute the average value of `EggsHatched::getHatched`, you can map the Stream to a `LongStream` and call the average method of that stream (or call `summaryStatistics`, which computes min,max,average,count and sum)

Comment: update your answer with summaryStatistics solution, thanks

Comment: @rocket there you go

Comment: thanks with much loyalty... I am sure many folks will tap from this well detailed solution/approach